# Does the following trignometric identity hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I did some algebraic manipulation and arrived at the following statement:
$\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\tan{x}}{\sqrt{\tan^2{x}+1}+1}$. I can't find anything about this identity on the web, but it seems to work for a lot of examples I've tried.

Note that this identity isn't a guess. I did some actual work to arrive to it.

For example:

$\tan{30}=\frac{\tan{60}}{\sqrt{\tan^2{60}+1}+1}$ 
$\tan{15}=\frac{\tan{30}}{\sqrt{\tan^2{30}+1}+1}$

It seems to work with all the halves of standard angles, and their subsequent halves. Is this an identity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your identity holds whenever $\cos x>0$, because then we have
$$\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{\tan^2x+1}+1}=\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt\frac1{\cos^2x}+1}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2}{2\cos^2\frac x2}=\tan\frac x2.$$
When $\cos x<0$, an analogous computation gives
$$\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{\tan^2x+1}+1}=\frac{\sin x}{-1+\cos x}=-\cot\frac x2.$$

Comment: Does $\cos{x} > 0$ imply that $x > 90$? Because this works for $x < 90$, as shown by the examples in my post.

Comment: Your identity works for $0^\circ\le x\lt 90^\circ$, where $\cos x > 0$.  But $\cos x > 0$ does not imply $x\gt 90^\circ$.  For example, $\cos -45^\circ > 0$ and your identity fails there.

Comment: $\displaystyle \,\sqrt{\,\rule{0pt}{5mm}a^{2}\,}\, = {\Large\color{red}{\left\vert\color{black}{a}\right\vert}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Since $\ds{\quad\tan\pars{x} = {2\tan\pars{x/2} \over 1 - \tan^{2}\pars{x/2}}}$:

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#44f}{%
\tan\pars{x} \over \root{\tan^{2}\pars{x} + 1} + 1}
\\[5mm] = & \
{2\tan\pars{x/2} \over
1 - \tan^{2}\pars{x/2} -
\bracks{1  +\tan^{2}\pars{x/2}}
\on{sgn}\pars{\tan^{2}\pars{x/2} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\tan\pars{x \over 2}} & \color{black}{\mbox{if}} &
\ds{\tan^{2}\pars{x \over 2} < 1}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\to \infty} & \color{black}{\mbox{if}} &
\ds{\tan^{2}\pars{x \over 2} \to 1^{-}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\to -\infty} & \color{black}{\mbox{if}} &
\ds{\tan^{2}\pars{x \over 2} \to 1^{+}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-\cot\pars{x \over 2}} & \color{black}{\mbox{if}} &
\ds{\tan^{2}\pars{x \over 2} > 1}
\end{array}\right.}} \\ &
\end{align}